# Is it possible to get list of system in which my userid is login

Tags: linux

I am working in a network having hundreds of servers , I want to know on which server my user id has been logging through terminal .
Is there any linux command exist for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to all theses machines, try:

```
for server in `cat serverlist.txt`; do ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" $server "echo `hostname`" >> serverreport.txt; done
```

where you replace `<username>` with the user. 
[depending of the implementation of `last` you may have to adapt parameters for head/tail]

(command adopted using `last <username>` from [Analyzing UID/GID conflicts](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/unix_linux_analyzing_user_group_uid_gid_conflicts1?lang=en))